# How can i get ModalDialog.args in aspx-page codebehind?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, aspnet-lifecycle

I have a button, that opens Modal Dialog using `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options)`
Options contains field "args".

I can read this "args" using window.frameElement.dialogArgs in javascript code of Dialog Page.

But i need to read this args in codebehind in methods like OnLoad, or OnPreRender.

I tried to save args to hiddenValue, but javascript is executing after OnPreRender.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing those arguments using the "args" object, you can append them in the QueryString in the Url of the page. Something like this:

```
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();

options.title = "My Dialog Title";
options.url = "/_layouts/DialogPage.aspx?Arg1=value&Arg2=value&Arg3=value";

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

And then in the code behind, you can use this to get the value of the args:

```
string valueOfArg1 = Page.Request.QueryString["Arg1"];
string valueOfArg2 = Page.Request.QueryString["Arg2"];
```

Comment: yes, but length of my 'args' can be more then 255 and i think that`s why this method will not work in this case

Comment: If that's the case and you need to pass large amounts of data between pages, then use Session State and retrieve the session state data on the modal page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a method similar to the one described here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/iewebdevelopment/thread/126fcea8-c28b-49ce-ad49-65884ffabeb6

Basically you open up an iframe pointing to about:blank. Then you create a new form that posts to the page you want to post to, along with a input value containing your data and targets your blank iframe. Then you submit the form.

Here's a sample function that does just that. Note that because of a bug with ie and dynamically renamed iframes, you have to remove and add the iframe back.

```
var openModalAndPostData = function (url, args) {
            var formUrl = url+ "?IsDlg=1";               
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
                var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
                options.url = "about:blank";
                options.width = 990;
                options.height = 560;
                options.args = args;
                options.dialogReturnValueCallback = closeCallback;
                SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
                var frame = $(".ms-dlgFrame");
                frame.attr("name", frame.attr("id"));
                var frameParent = frame.parent();
                var html = frame[0].outerHTML;
                frame.remove();
                frameParent.append(html);
                var form = $("<form action='" + formUrl + "' method='post' target='" + frame.attr("name") + "'><input type='hidden' name='args' value='" + JSON.stringify(args) + "' /><input type='submit' /></form>");
                $('body').append(form);
                form.submit();
                form.remove();
            }, 'sp.js');
        }
```

If you use this, then you can access your modal's args in the codebehind using "Request.Form["args"]